# difference between printing and returning recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion, printing, return

When writing a recursive function in Python, what is the difference between using "print" and "return"? I understand the difference between the two when using them for iterative functions, but don't see any rhyme or reason to why it may be more important to use one over the other in a recursive function.

Comment: `return` isn't "print and leave the function". `return` communicates with a function's caller; `print` sends output out of the entire program. It's like the difference between emailing a report to your boss and emailing it to the media.

Answer (score 3):

What a strange question.

The two are completely different, and their correct use in a recursive function is just as important as in an iterative one. You might even say *more* important: after all, in an iterative function, you return the result once only; but in a recursive function, you must return something at every step, otherwise the calling step has nothing to work on.

To illustrate: if you are doing mergesort, for example, the recursive function at each stage must return the sorted sublist. If it simply prints it, without returning it, then the caller will not get the sublist to sort, so cannot then merge the two sorted sublists into a single sorted list for passing further up the stack.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/qXY9oZ for an example of a recursive function that does not return anything.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower but that's not something you'd ever actually do, at least not in Python: you might do it in a purely functional language, but in Python we have iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I might add that from a Functional Programming perspective print is a side affect as it pertains to return.

Consider programming as an extent of mathematics. Your function takes a set of inputs, performs an action on them and returns the computation. Print in this case is not a computation. It causes an interaction with the system's IO to provide output to the user.

As for return and print in a recursive function, return is the only required operation. Recursion requires inputs, an optional computation and a test. The test defines if the function will be called again with the computation modified inputs or if the modified inputs are the final solution to the overall equation. No where in this process is print required, and per Functional purists, it really has no place in a recursive function ( unless its computation IS to print).

Answer (score 0):

The difference between print and return in a recursive function is similar to the difference in an iterative function. Print is direct output to the user and return is the result of the function. You have to return at every step or the function will never end and you will get an error.

For example-

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

If you used print instead the function would never end.